# Swift Firebase retrieving data in smarter way?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `UITableView` which displays user posts. The post contains a `post-image`, `post-description`, `post-owner-uid`, `post-owner username` and `post-owner profile picture`. When a user uploads a post, it saves those 5 objects to the Firebase post node.

```
let Post = Post(description: description, imgUrl: imgUrl, postOwnerUID: postOwnerUID, postOwnerName: postOwnerName, postOwnerImg: postOwnerImg)
```

Then, the app retrieves it and displays it on the `tableCell`. However, I would like to ask what is the best practice to save all the data in the `Post` node (*even the user data*) or retrieve user data from the `User` node by using the `postOwnerUID`(*User uid*)? If so how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when displaying a post, you always need the user's name, it might make sense to keep the user's name on hand within the Post node. However, you'll need to maintain the name for the user's every post. By having a reference to the user's uid, you only have to update the user in one place.

```
{
    "posts": {
        "p1": {
            "owner": { "u1": true },
            "description": "...",
            "imgUrl": "http://..."
        }
    },
    "user-posts": {
        "u1": {
            "p1": true
        }
    }
    "users": {
        "u1": {
            "name": "John",
            "imgUrl": "http://..."
        }
    }
}
```

You can get your posts and retrieve their owner with a separate request.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath('posts')

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

    guard let json = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }

    let post = Post(...)

    let uid = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("owner").key
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath('users/\(uid)')

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let owner = Owner(...)

        post.owner = owner
    })
})
```

You should also check out FirebaseUI-iOS, makes populating your table with Firebase data really easy https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Would it be more complex if creating a new node for the post?

Comment: I figure it out why It 2 need paths! It prevent any changes on the core user data with the post user data. However, I think I still need sometimes to understand your example haha:(